# Array keeps adding to all indexes the same value from the list loop

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm using 2 arrays, one is `arrayWeight` and the other is `arrayId`.They both receiving the values from database I have through List.

```
List<oldDetails> details = olddb.getDetails();
        for (oldDetails cn : details) { //Adding weights and id of all time to an array.
            double num = cn.getWeight();
            int id = cn.getId();
            Log.d("num", "equals: " + num);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                arrayWeight[i] = num;
                arrayId[i] = id;
            }
        }
Log.d("Array", "equals: " + Arrays.toString(arrayWeight));
```

After LogCat every step on the for loops that what I've received:

```
D/num: equals: 70.6
D/num: equals: 60.7
D/num: equals: 8000.0
D/num: equals: 80.6
D/Array: equals: [80.6, 80.6, 80.6, 80.6]
```

Now I'm willing to achieve this goal in my array:

```
D/num: equals: 70.6
D/num: equals: 60.7
D/num: equals: 8000.0
D/num: equals: 80.6
D/Array: equals: [70.6, 60.6, 8000.0, 80.6]
```

How can I fix the problem of the array receiving only one value from the list and not all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner loop copies each value from `detail` to every value in the arrays `arrayWeigth` and `arrayId`, thus on the last iteration it replaces every value. Use a single regular for loop instead of nested loops. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < details.size(); i++) {
    OldDetails cn = details.get(i);
    double num = cn.getWeight();
    int id = cn.getId();
    Log.d("num", "equals: " + num);
    arrayWeight[i] = num;
    arrayId[i] = id; 
}
```

**or** the shorter,

```
for (int i = 0; i < details.size(); i++) {
    OldDetails cn = details.get(i);
    arrayWeight[i] = cn.getWeight();
    arrayId[i] = cn.getId();
    Log.d("num", "equals: " + arrayWeight[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think you miss understood the code, details is an list.

Comment: @YotamDahan Edited. Next time, for better help faster you should include pertinent details like that in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was confusion, I thought it was pretty clear. thanks though.